# if($bans[$i]['ip'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])

Tags: plugins, wordpress

i have created a website with Ultimate video curator using wordpress, also buy a plugin "wp sensei" for protect this site from hacking. I have also installed this plugin, but when i clicked on activate showing me

"Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error." and

"Warning: Illegal string offset 'ip' in /home4/worldvj5/public_html/halloweencostumes/wp-content/plugins/wp-sensei/wplockup.php on line 108

Warning: Illegal string offset 'time' in /home4/worldvj5/public_html/halloweencostumes/wp-content/plugins/wp-sensei/wplockup.php on line 119

Fatal error: Cannot unset string offsets in /home4/worldvj5/public_html/halloweencostumes/wp-content/plugins/wp-sensei/wplockup.php on line 120"

so what is the main problem, and how to solve it, please solve this problem.

and when i go to this page with 108 line in wp sensei, i see that "if($bans[$i]['ip'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])"

please help me.

Comment: Did your sensei teach your debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Odds are, the $bans array is empty. Add a bogus IP to be banned using the plugin, and then try it again.

Comment: how to add a bogus IP that had beed banned? please i hope you can help me.thanks

Comment: You will have to look into the plugin wp sensei for doing this.